# How to update Wordpress files on Heroku?

Tags: php, wordpress, heroku

I successfully deployed a Wordpress  website on Heroku.
Here is what I did:

1. Download wordpress
2. Push all file on a Github repository
3. Create Heroku app
4. Link Heroku app to Github repository
5. Create clearDB database and update to wordpress config file
6. Deploy

Everythings is working fine. But whenever I update a file on the github repository and redeploy the heroku app, all user generated content are getting overwritten such as plugins and media contents.

How can I update my wordpress source code without losing any content?

Comment: Have you created an environment variable for database connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has an ephemeral file system, meaning that any files that are saved to the Heroku instance while running, will be removed on your next application push. This is why there aren't many easy buildpacks for WordPress. All files "added" to your app have to be hosted elsewhere, like S3. Which makes it not necessarily ideal for a WordPress app without significant modifications.

I use Heroku for a lot of our infrastructure, but for WordPress sites I use Flywheel. (http://getflywheel.com) They have great support, have a handy local app that harnesses a virtual machine that is virtually identical to their live builds, and support intelligent Staging environments. I use DeployHQ to automate the build process similar to how Heroku does it. Pushing my repo will trigger a DeployHQ build to push code to Staging or Production, without affecting any user uploaded content/etc.

Comment: $25/MO - too expensive, I think.